# How do I access List items in order to change their values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu, listitem

I want to dynamically fill a drop down list with text and values using a different table from my database.  I am using this code:

```
    protected void MachineGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = e.NewEditIndex;
        var ddl = MachineGrid.Rows[index].FindControl("OSDropDownList") as DropDownList;
    }
```

To access the drop down list.  I then have tried using both of the following code snippets to modify one of the List items, but both have given me the following error

"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Code 1:

```
        var li = ddl.SelectedItem;
        li.Text = "test";
```

Code 2:

```
        var li = ddl.Items[0];
        li.Text = "test";
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean DataTextField and DataValueField?

Comment: I'm not sure... I don't think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something that will 
fill your datatable via a query and provide a datasource to the dropdownlist.

```
yourDropDownList.DataSource= dt;
yourDropDownList.DataTextField="StringColumnName";
yourDropDownList.DataValueField="integerColumnName";
yourDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Comment: I did not properly ask my question the first time.  I would appreciate it if you looked at it now that I have improved it.

Comment: Try this 
foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in YourGridViewID.Rows)
            {           

                DropDownList yourDropDownList= (DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("yourDropDownListID");
                string selectvalue = yourDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        }

Comment: This is somewhat helpful but still doesn't get at the core issue. I don't want to change the selected string, rather I want to dynamically change all of strings in the list items under the drop down list